# Image Quality difference in android os versions

Tags: android

In android 4.0.3 image quality of my app is fine but in android 2.0 the image quality is not as good why?

Comment: are you using the same image for both the OS? What are the screen size/resolution of your devices?

Comment: could you post an example?

Comment: I created an android game its display is very pleasing in android 4.0.3 but the color tone changed in android 2.2. I used same image in both hdpi device.

Comment: @RohithRNair did you test in on differnct devices? If yes - it could be a display quality difference. In cheap LG E400 you'l see different colors than on LG Nexus 4. If it's on emulator - make sure you configured the display exactly and just changed OS version.

Comment: I tested it in Sony Xperia J ST26i(android 4.0.3) and Samsung Galaxy(android 2.2)

Comment: @Doctoror Drive is this due to display quality difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the display quality and number of colors on devices you test differs. Try [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.screentest) on both devices, or upload the same HQ pictures to both devices to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly because of the resolutions and display quality of diff devices. For ex. when a play a game on cheaper devices quality is low, on contrary , on config devices it shows awesome.